# Django Contact Form send html emails

Tags: html, django, contact-form

Is there a way to use the django-contact-form to send a html email?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just looked up the source and it's not built in.

You can certainly modify it however you please -- it's a **very** simple form and very readable.

You'd need to add a html_template variable/path and modify the save line, and add a way to specify which template to use.

```
def save(self, fail_silently=False):
    """
    Build and send the email message.

    """
    data = self.get_message_dict()
    msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject=data['subject'], body=data['message'], from_email=data['from_email'], to=data['recipient_list'])

    msg.attach_alternative(loader.render_to_string('path_to_my_html_template.html', self.get_context()), "text/html")
    msg.send(fail_silently=fail_silently)
```

This is just easier to keep all of your changes in one spot.

Otherwise, you could re-write most of the code and change the method names and the strings in `get_message_dict()` to reflect the new field names for `EmailMessage`

Frankly, i'm not sure why send_mail should have different keywords than `EmailMessage`

Comment: I get an error "__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'message'" with the msg = line of your code and line 73 of the view "form.save(fail_silently=fail_silently)"

Comment: Ok, since send_mail converts all of the arguments to the correct EmailMessage ones, with the way this was written you're going to have to change most of the code here (names) or come with other ways to get the keywords right.. updating post